# Rspec, fail testing date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test this :

```
  it "should calculate the max_validation_deadline" do
    tasting = Tasting.create!(valid_attributes)
    expect ( tasting.max_validation_deadline.to_s ).to eq(today_plus_one.to_s)
  end
```

But it fails. When I'm debugging it I'm having this.

```
(byebug) tasting.max_validation_deadline.to_s
"2016-12-13 01:00:00 UTC"
(byebug) today_plus_one.to_s
"2016-12-13 01:00:00 UTC"
(byebug) expect ( tasting.max_validation_deadline.to_s ).to eq(today_plus_one.to_s)
*** ArgumentError Exception: bad value for range
```

Why does it fail saying `bad value for range` as I'm passing two strings ?

**Edit**

Here is a full byebug when I'm not testing with `to_s`.

```
 bundle exec rspec spec/models/tasting_spec.rb
........
[76, 85] in server/spec/models/tasting_spec.rb
   76:   end
   77:
   78:   it "should calculate the max_validation_deadline" do
   79:     tasting = Tasting.create!(valid_attributes)
   80:     byebug
=> 81:     expect ( tasting.max_validation_deadline ).to eq(today_plus_one)
   82:   end
   83:
   84:   it "should calculate the current_opened_places" do
   85:     tasting = Tasting.create!(valid_attributes)
(byebug) expect ( tasting.max_validation_deadline ).to eq(today_plus_one)
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `to' for Tue, 13 Dec 2016 01:00:00 UTC +00:00:Time

nil
(byebug)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a formatting error.

Replace...

```
expect ( tasting.max_validation_deadline ).to eq(today_plus_one)
```

with...

```
expect( tasting.max_validation_deadline ).to eq(today_plus_one)
```

In the first method, the `(expression).to` is the passed parameter, when it should be just `(expression)`

You can demonstrate this problem easily...

```
expect ("hello").to eq("hello")
```

generates "bad value for range"

```
expect("hello").to eq("hello")
```

is fine.